# Echo out result_array() as an array without foreach

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How can I print out the values of an array returned by codeignitor result_array() without using foreach. I want the array for it so I can add it up because the price field is encrypted. There is my code.
The price field is encrypted so I cannot use select_sum

```
$prices = $this->db->select('price')->from('orders')->get()->result_array();

return $price;
```

And my controller is

```
$data['prices'] = $this->orders->get_prices();
```

my view is like

```
array_sum($this->encryption->decrypt($prices))
```

Comment: Can you provide further information? Why can't you use foreach? What format are you trying to print?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot decrypt entire array like this. Instead of it you have to decrypt single-sigle element of it

```
$price_sum = 0;
foreach ($prices as $price) {
    $price_sum += $this->encryption->decrypt($price);
}
echo $price_sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  `row()`  to select the table without foreach. But it just one row.

This is the query example

```
$this->db->select('price');
$this->db->from('orders');
$prices = $this-db-get();
return $price->row();
```

In your controller

```
$data['prices'] = $this->orders->get_prices();
$this->load->view('yourview',$data);
```

In your view

```
<?php echo $prices->price; ?>
```